# Is it possible to automatically find and print xpath of text, for which i know the exact and unique text at the website?

Tags: python

Many website changes there xpath frequently. But they always have same data/text in it.

It is very hectic to always write an xpath for everything every time the xpath changes. Is there any solution for get/print xpath for a webelement, so that i can use it anytime the xpath changes.

Comment: so you want the data for an element that has text as `<p> Products 5</p>`
so, if you want to check for element with text 'Products' , you want the entire 'Products 5' extracted?

Comment: Can you simply starts with //p[contains(text(),'Products ')] ?